# SQL Server - Averages MTD and FYTD

Tags: sql-server, average

I am trying to calculate averages per month and fiscal year to date.  I have the following query but am having trouble with Fiscal Year to Date portion.

I have had some help with the query but am stuck on how to add the # of workdays in a month without adding # of workdays for each record.  I've searched for sample queries demonstrating the averages in a UNION ALL type format but no luck so far.  Only my second post so please let me know if I have neglected to provide enough information.

Here is current state query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Distinct_Appt') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Distinct_Appt;

select distinct cast(Appt_DateTime as date) Appt_Date
, MONTH(Appt_DateTime) CM
, YEAR(Appt_DateTime) CY
, MONTH(DATEADD(m,3,Appt_DateTime)) FM
, YEAR(DATEADD(m,3,Appt_DateTime)) FY
, DAY(EOMONTH(Appt_DateTime)) Days_in_Month
, DATENAME(dw,Appt_DateTime) Day_of_Week
into #Distinct_Appt
from Ntier_57539.PM.vwGenPatApptInfo with (nolock) 
where Appt_DateTime BETWEEN  DATEADD(m,-3, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(m,-3,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1))
and DATENAME(dw,Appt_DateTime) not in ('Saturday','Sunday');


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WeekDays') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #WeekDays;
select cast(Appt_Date as date) Appt_Date
,  da.CM
,  da.CY
,  FM
,  FY
, Days_in_Month
, Day_of_Week
, wdn.WeekDays 
INTO #WeekDays
FROM #Distinct_Appt da with (nolock)
inner join ( select CM, CY,sum(case when DATENAME(dw,Appt_Date) not in ('Saturday','Sunday') then 1 else 0 end )  WeekDays
                           from #Distinct_Appt 
                           group by CM, CY
                           ) wdn 
on da.CY  = wdn.CY and da.CM= wdn.CM
order by 1;

--select * from #WeekDays

SELECT 
'MTD' as 'Office Metric'
,pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr as Location 

,vwef.Appt_Category_Desc as 'Appt Category'
,'FY'+cast(wd.FY as varchar(6)) AS 'Fiscal Year'
,'CY'+cast(wd.CY as varchar(6)) AS 'Calendar Year'
,CONVERT(varchar(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 100) + ' - ' + cast(YEAR(pt.Appt_DateTime) as varchar) as 'Appt Month/Year'
,Convert(char(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 0) as 'Appt Month'

,wd.Days_in_Month '# of Days'
,wd.WeekDays as '# of Workdays'
,AVG(DATEDIFF(day,  appt.DateTime_Scheduled,appt.Appointment_DateTime)) as 'Average Time Between Scheduling and Actual Appt'
, count(pt.Appt_ID)  '# of Appts'
, count(case when vwef.Appt_Category_Desc is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end)  '# of Visits'

, count(case when pt.Appt_Cancelled_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'Cancellations'
, count(case when pt.Appt_NoShow_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'No Show'
, count(case when pt.Appt_Confirmed_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'Confirmation'

FROM Ntier_57539.PM.vwGenPatApptInfo pt 
LEFT JOIN [Ntier_57539].[PM].[vwEncounterForms] vwef on pt.Appt_Encounter_Number=vwef.Encounter_Number
left join [Ntier_57539].[dbo].[vUAI_Appointments] appt on pt.Appt_ID=appt.Appointment_ID
inner join #WeekDays wd on  cast(pt.Appt_DateTime as date) = wd.Appt_Date

WHERE  pt.Appt_DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-2)) AND EOMONTH(Getdate(), -1) 
and DATENAME(dw,pt.Appt_DateTime) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
AND pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr LIKE '%ALPH%' AND vwef.Appt_Category_Desc ='Follow Up'

group by pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr

 ,vwef.Appt_Category_Desc 
,'FY'+cast(wd.FY as varchar(6))  
,'CY'+cast(wd.CY as varchar(6)) 
,CONVERT(varchar(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 100) + ' - ' + cast(YEAR(pt.Appt_DateTime) as varchar) 
,Convert(char(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 0) 
,wd.Days_in_Month 
,wd.WeekDays

UNION ALL

SELECT 
'FYTD' as 'Office Metric'
,pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr as Location 

,vwef.Appt_Category_Desc as 'Appt Category'
,'FY'+cast(wd.FY as varchar(6)) AS 'Fiscal Year'
,'CY'+cast(wd.CY as varchar(6)) AS 'Calendar Year'
,'' as 'Appt Month/Year'
,''  as 'Appt Month'

,wd.Days_in_Month '# of Days'
,wd.WeekDays as '# of Workdays'
,AVG(DATEDIFF(day,  appt.DateTime_Scheduled,appt.Appointment_DateTime)) as 'Average Time Between Scheduling and Actual Appt'
, count(pt.Appt_ID)  '# of Appts'
, count(case when vwef.Appt_Category_Desc is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end)  '# of Visits'

, count(case when pt.Appt_Cancelled_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'Cancellations'
, count(case when pt.Appt_NoShow_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'No Show'
, count(case when pt.Appt_Confirmed_Date is not null then pt.Appt_Encounter_Number end) 'Confirmation'

FROM Ntier_57539.PM.vwGenPatApptInfo pt 
LEFT JOIN [Ntier_57539].[PM].[vwEncounterForms] vwef on pt.Appt_Encounter_Number=vwef.Encounter_Number
left join [Ntier_57539].[dbo].[vUAI_Appointments] appt on pt.Appt_ID=appt.Appointment_ID
inner join #WeekDays wd on  cast(pt.Appt_DateTime as date) = wd.Appt_Date

WHERE  pt.Appt_DateTime BETWEEN  DATEADD(m,-3, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(m,-3,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1))
and pt.Appt_DateTime < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
and DATENAME(dw,pt.Appt_DateTime) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
AND pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr LIKE '%ALPH%' AND vwef.Appt_Category_Desc ='Follow Up'

group by pt.Appt_Sched_Location_Descr

 ,vwef.Appt_Category_Desc 
,'FY'+cast(wd.FY as varchar(6))  
,'CY'+cast(wd.CY as varchar(6)) 
,CONVERT(varchar(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 100) + ' - ' + cast(YEAR(pt.Appt_DateTime) as varchar) 
,Convert(char(3), pt.Appt_DateTime, 0) 
,wd.Days_in_Month 
,wd.WeekDays
```

I'm attaching results I have with current state.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iauM9.png)

Comment: am stuck on how to sum the # of workdays in a month without summing  # of workdays for each record.

Comment: I think you probably need to try to simplify the problem down and ask a question where preople don't have to deal with or guess what's in your production tables.

Comment: Thanks TDP, seems obvious now :(.  Is there any way I can edit or delete this post and start fresh given the specificity of my query?

Comment: So, to simplify, I am trying to calculate Averages MTD and FYTD, using records from an appointment table and appt types.  Averages MTD, are just a simple calculation but FYTD is more difficult.  It was suggested that I use UNION ALL and connect averages of each type but my summed workdays sum all records rather than summing # of workdays each month, to be divided by # of months.....  Google and search of site did not produce an example I could follow.  There is an image above, click on "enter image description here" which shows my current results.  Expected results would be 1 row for each type

Comment: What current result do you get for the `FYTD` portion of the query?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but you can solve difficult problems more easily (and get help here more easily) by breaking a problem down into its most basic form.

Something like this, which you can re-run:

```
-- SET UP TEST DATA
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int)

insert into @t1
select 1 union
select 2

insert into @t2
select 1

-- SHOW DATA
select * from @t1
select * from @t2

-- WANTED OUTPUT
-- 2, NULL

-- ATTEMPT
select *
from @t1 a
join @t2 b 
    on a.id = b.id and b.id = null

-- A SOLUTION
select *
from @t1 a
left join @t2 b 
    on a.id = b.id 
where b.id is null
```

Comment: Thanks TDP for your patience with my first attempt.  Will use this as a model moving forward.